# How to use case_when for factor names

Tags: r

```
SA = c("Argentina", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Chile", "Colombia", "Ecuador", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Uruguay", "Venezuela")
AF1 = gapminder %>%
  mutate(
    country,
    continent == case_when(
      country == SA ~ "South America",
      TRUE ~ as.character(continent)
     )
  )
```

I am trying to rename the country in SA to South America, but it does not work.

Comment: Try with `%in%`, not with `==`.

Comment: Assign with `=`, not `==`

Comment: These two works.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you're looking for.  I'm not sure why 'country' is in the mutate because you're not actually changing it.  For the continent, you are looking to see if the value is **in**  SA, not *equal to* SA. Does this work?

```
SA = c("Argentina", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Chile", "Colombia", "Ecuador", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Uruguay", "Venezuela")
AF1 = gapminder %>%
  mutate(
    continent = case_when(
      country %in% SA ~ "South America",
      TRUE ~ continent
     )
  )
```

Comment: It does not work. I am going to rename continent for the country in SA.

Comment: There is no change for the continent name.

Comment: Try the updated code.  Originally there was a double equals (==) pointing to the case_when. It should be singular.  (This is difficult to test without sample data)

Comment: I changed my original code with %in%, and assign = instead of ==. it works

Comment: Please accept answer if this answers the question! Thanks :)